# xcode auto layout is messed up after pressing a button

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

So I have a view controller with two separate views in it. I can switch between the two view by pressing a button. The first time I switch everything works fine. But the second time I switch (go back to the first) The view gets pushed up and significantly. I have all the constraints in there that I need, I just don't know what is wrong with it. 
Here is the example of what is happening.

Before I press the button and switch views
[image: Before I switch views]

And after I switch back to the view from the other view.
[image: After i switch views]

And here is how I am change between the two views.
There is a button that just set the view in the same view controller. 
[image]

Comment: Disregarding the Auto Layout issues, it looks like you (from seeing your pictures) you are better served using a Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: switch view means have you multiple view in horizontal scrollview ? or you have multiple view controller for that ? how you switching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using two different view controllers and navigating between them when pressing your button?
Or are you switching views in the same view controller?

**UPDATE:**

I created a simple app with 2 views and used `sendsubviewtoback()` to change the views on button pressed. It worked Perfectly fine.

Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Second: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var First: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(Second)
        Second.hidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func demo(){}

    @IBAction func switchview(sender: UIButton){
        if sender.titleForState(.Normal) == "Next"{
         print("clicked next")
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(Second)
            Second.hidden = false

    }
        else{
            print("prev clicked")
            self.view.sendSubviewToBack(Second)
            Second.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

When the application loads:
[image]
When I click on Next:
[image]
When I click on Prev:
[image]

Hope this is what You are looking for. :)

Comment: the same view controller. I have two views within it. I which like this;
    @IBAction func onLogoutClick(sender: AnyObject) {
       
        self.view = LoginView
    }        and then switch to the other one like this   self.view = MyPageView

Comment: Do you have a common button for switching or different buttons for different views?

Comment: Thank you. i appreciate it it works now. That was driving me nuts